# inconsistent output between sql developer and stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

When I execute the below query it will return C507,
but when I use it as sub query in one of my stored procedure it only returns C.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (    SELECT MAX (REGEXP_SUBSTR ('C507|C507',
                                       '[^|]+',
                                       1,
                                       LEVEL))
                      serial
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                        LENGTH ('C507|C507')
                      - LENGTH (REPLACE ('C507|C507', '|', ''))
                      + 1);
```

Comment: What does that stored procedure do? Query - as you said - returns C507, so it is probably *something* within the procedure that is responsible for what you're saying. BTW, `CONNECT BY`  can be rewritten as `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count('C507|C507', '|') + 1` (easier to read).

Comment: the SP will basically goes like this: select dep_id,                          
(SELECT *
  FROM (    SELECT MAX (REGEXP_SUBSTR ('name',
                                       '[^|]+',
                                       1,
                                       LEVEL))
                      serial
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                        LENGTH ('name')
                      - LENGTH (REPLACE ('name', '|', ''))
                      + 1))
from dept
where dep_id = 2;

data:
  dep_id  name
  2       angelo|angelo
  2       ' '

Comment: This query is, probably, wrong. `'name'` takes a string "name" literally, it is not a variable.

Comment: sorry, should be. data: dep_id  
  2   
  2   
  
  name
   angelo|angelo
   ' '  /*<-a space*/            select dep_id,                          
(SELECT *
  FROM (    SELECT MAX (REGEXP_SUBSTR (d.name,
                                       '[^|]+',
                                       1,
                                       LEVEL))
                      serial
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                        LENGTH (d.name)
                      - LENGTH (REPLACE (d.name, '|', ''))
                      + 1))
from dept d
where dep_id = 2;

Comment: Please add details to your question, not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see any problem( *tell us if your way is different* ) :

```
SQL> Create or Replace Procedure Get_Serial( o_value out varchar2 ) Is
  2  Begin
  3    Select *
  4      Into o_value
  5      From (Select Max(Regexp_Substr('C507|C507', '[^|]+', 1, Level)) serial
  6              From Dual
  7            Connect By Level <= Length('C507|C507') -
  8                       Length(Replace('C507|C507', '|', '')) + 1);
  9  End;
 10  /

Procedure created

SQL> var serial varchar2;
SQL> exec Get_Serial(:serial);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
serial
---------
C507
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit difficult to guess what you really are doing (as you posted different queries with different input data, unformatted within the comment) so - have a look a this example.

I've modified your last query so that it returns `DEP_ID` and `MAX` piece of the `NAME` column.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE dept
  2  (
  3     dep_id   NUMBER,
  4     name     VARCHAR2 (50)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO dept VALUES (1, 'mirko|mirko');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO dept VALUES (2, 'angelo|angelo');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO dept VALUES (3, 'angelo|mirko');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM dept;

    DEP_ID NAME
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 mirko|mirko
         2 angelo|angelo
         3 angelo|mirko

SQL>
SQL>     SELECT d.dep_id,
  2             MAX (REGEXP_SUBSTR (d.name,
  3                                 '[^|]+',
  4                                 1,
  5                                 LEVEL))
  6                serial
  7        FROM dept d
  8       WHERE dep_id = &par_dep_id
  9  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (d.name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (d.name, '|', '')) + 1
 10    GROUP BY d.dep_id;
Enter value for par_dep_id: 1

    DEP_ID SERIAL
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 mirko

SQL> /
Enter value for par_dep_id: 2

    DEP_ID SERIAL
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         2 angelo

SQL> /
Enter value for par_dep_id: 3

    DEP_ID SERIAL
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         3 mirko

SQL>
```

Saying that you have problems with a stored procedure: you should post (by editing your initial message) its code. Is it really a procedure, or a function? Query returns 2 values - does that procedure have 2 OUT parameters? If it is a function, what does it return (what datatype)?

From my point of view, query is OK *as is*, but - you wouldn't be posting a question here if there's no problem, but it is unclear *which* problem you have.

Once again: I suggest you post copy/paste of your own SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded. Without it, we're just blindly guessing.

Comment: CREATE TABLE dept
(
  id NUMBER,
  dep_id   NUMBER,
   name     VARCHAR2 (50)
); INSERT INTO dept VALUES (1,2, 'angelo|angelo');
INSERT INTO dept VALUES (2,2, ' '); my data would look like this. sorry for the confusion. yes the query returns ok if you put it like this in the SP, select MAX (REGEXP_SUBSTR (d.name,
                                '[^|]+',
                                1,
                                LEVEL))
               serial from...... but when select * from ( select          MAX (REGEXP_SUBSTR (d.name,  '[^|]+',1, LEVEL))
               serial from..........

Comment: Once again: don't post that as a comment - it is difficult to read, not everything is being posted - shortly, pretty much useless. **Edit your question, post every piece of information we might need to reproduce your situation**

Comment: I understand, apologies the SP was very long and complicated, I will try to recreate it first on the simplest way I can and share it here..

Answer (score 0):

I created a function for this query and call it on my SP instead of using it as a sub query on my stored procedure.